# What happens if you set a group outside of aes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I don't understand what happens when I assign a constant value to group outside of the aes function in ggplot2.

Suppose I have the following data frame (called it BOD)

```
Time  demand
  <fct>  <dbl>
1 1        8.3
2 2       10.3
3 3       19  
4 4       16  
5 5       15.6
6 7       19.8
```

If I try to generate a line plot and specifying the grouping inside aes
(since Time is a categorical variable) I get what I want

```
ggplot(data = BOD, aes(x = Time, y = demand,group=1)) + 
    geom_line()
```

However, the following code

```
ggplot(data = BOD, aes(x = Time, y = demand), group=1) + 
    geom_line()
```

gave me a message of

> geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need ## to adjust the group aesthetic?

So my question is what is going on when I specify a grouping outside of aes ? Is there ever a reason to assign a grouping outside of aes ?

Comment: While I cannot imagine the utility of setting `group=` outside of `aes()`, I also find the behavior counter-intuitive. Aesthetics set outside of `aes` will be the same for all values in `data=`, suggesting that instead of *"each group consists of only one observation"*, I would have expected *"only one group with all observations"* (which is not wrong, and should not receive an error/warning). Odd behavior, perhaps, but perhaps a better question to you: what are you trying to do such that setting a constant grouping variable seems like one possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing strange here. If you study `help("ggplot")` you see that it has three (+ one deprecated) parameters: `data`, which expects a data.frame (or something that can be turned into one), `mapping` which expects an `aes` call and `...`. So, in your example, `group=1` can only be passed to `...`. But the help says that `...` is currently not used and thus
`group=1` is simply ignored. If you want to set anything (groups, colors, etc.) outside of `aes` you have to do so in a `geom_*` or `stat_*` call:

```
ggplot(data = BOD, aes(x = Time, y = demand)) + 
  geom_line(group = 1)
#works
```